# add base url to angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm starting in angular.
I making my firts app and I try to define a base url but I cant to do work it.

I have seen some posts where say use this:

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
 ...
  providers: [{provide:APP_BASE_HREF,useValue:'/my/app'}],
 ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

that looks easy but dont work.

I create the app with Angular-cli, and then add this lines to app.module.ts. then run ng serve but nothing happens. The app running on localhost:4200

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? When you provide the value (`useValue`), you assigned the value tot he global variable `APP_BASE_HREF` - What do you get if you `console.log(APP_BASE_HREF);` in your app.component?

Answer (score 0):

Provider is use to DI of services.
If you want to use static value like URL you can either :

1. **Environment variables**

In your environments folder, you can add new values in each environment file.

```
 export const environment = {
  production: false,
  APP_BASE_HREF : '/my/app'
 };
```

Then you can use it import it everywhere

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment'
```

It allows you to set multiple variables values depending on your environment.

```
 ng serve --env=prod
```

2. **Constant settings**

If you just want static value for every environment, you can create a setting file.

```
 export const SERVICESETTINGS = {
     USER_URL : '/api/user',  
 }
```

Then you have just to import in your class

```
import  { SERVICESETTINGS } from 'app/configs/serviceSettings';
```